# aspectj pointcut expression doing an or give inconsistent binding

Tags: java, spring-aop

I have the following

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.foo..*.*(..))")
public void logExecTimeAllMethods() {
}

//intercept all methods that are annotated with @LogExecTime
@Pointcut("@annotation(logExecTime)")
public void logExecTimeAnnotatedMethods(LogExecTime logExecTime) {
}

//add advice to above interceptors
@Around("logExecTimeAnnotatedMethods(logExecTime) || logExecTimeAllMethods()")
public Object logExecTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, LogExecTime logExecTime) throws Throwable {
```

in the logExecTime If i replace the || with && it compiles file but with || I get "inconsistent binding"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the annotation. That is only possible if it is present, which it doesn't have to if you use an OR-construct. If it's only a marker, you won't need it in the advice. If it contains valuable information you intend to use, you should handle that case in it's own advice.